# Help in making some symbol in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want make a symbol like this:

[image]

Is it possible to make in tikz?

Comment: `coffee stains!`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  broken/.style={
    white,
    decoration={random steps, amplitude=.3mm, 
            segment length=.5mm}, decorate},
  very broken/.style={
    white,
    decoration={random steps, amplitude=1mm, 
            segment length=.3mm}, decorate},
}

\draw[red!50!black, line width=1mm] circle(13mm);
\draw[red!50!black,  line width=2mm] circle(10mm);

\foreach \a in {0,15,...,360}{
    \filldraw[broken, fill=white, draw=white, line width=1pt, line join=round]
      ($(\a+2*rnd:.8+0.2*rnd)$)
               ++($(0+10*rnd:.1+0.2*rnd)$) -- 
               ++($(90+10*rnd:.1+0.2*rnd)$) -- 
               ++($(180+10*rnd:.1+0.2*rnd)$) --
               ++($(270+10*rnd:.1+0.2*rnd)$) -- cycle;
     }
\foreach \a in {0,5,...,360}{
    \filldraw[very broken, fill=white, draw=white, line width=.15pt, line join=round]
      ($(\a+2*rnd:1.1+0.3*rnd)$)
               ++($(0+10*rnd:.0+0.1*rnd)$) -- 
               ++($(90+10*rnd:.0+0.1*rnd)$) -- 
               ++($(180+10*rnd:.0+0.1*rnd)$) --
               ++($(270+10*rnd:.0+0.1*rnd)$) -- cycle;
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```